# Use a MATCH result as a formula entry

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a sheet that pulls data from lots of other sheets.  The data can shift columns from time to time.  I have charts that auto fill based on the data sheet.

I used the below method to make the values auto populate on the chart sheet.

Finds the column and builds the sheet reference:

```
="Summary!" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("NEW_PN",Summary!1:1,0),4),1,"") & ":" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("NEW_PN",Summary!1:1,0),4),1,"")
```

`INDIRECT` to dynamically fill the `COUNTIF` formula:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A9),"yes")
```

[image]

Comment: I may be having a bad day, and missed it completely, but what is the question?

Comment: How did you post the formula that way?  I am trying to figure out this form.  I get tons of stuff from here so when I figure out something I was not able to find I am try to give back to the community.

Comment: Oh and no question just a post.  Maybe someone that know more about Excel formulas than me can do this in a more elegant way.

Comment: 4 spaces in front of a line makes it look like that or your can highlight the text you want formatted like that and use the block quote button